# List or schema of all dcm4chee xsl templates

Tags: dcm4che

recently we managed to solved some data transferring problem by finding out there is additional .xsl we could use. Since .xsl files seems to be main way of controlling information flow in dcm4chee (beside jmx configurations ofc) im wondering whether there is some kind of list or index or something like that with enumerated all .xsl files one could use and their places in workflow.
I mean it would  be nice to know exactly in which points we could have some influence on process.
I tried to google something like that but no success so far :/

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some online list of demo `.xsl` files is available at

https://svn.code.sf.net/p/dcm4che/svn/dcm4chee/dcm4chee-arc/trunk/dcm4jboss-hl7/src/etc/conf/dcm4chee-hl7

Which one will be used is configurable through the jmx console and the configuration is then written back into the configuration files.

So searching for `.xsl` both as file extension and as full text search pattern in your dcm4chee installation directory will point you exactly to the places where the workflow can be influenced.

---

It is Java-style, Linux-style open source project so don't expect it to be too user friendly or Google friendly. I'm not aware of any easy to consume overview table/list/index but it would be nice to have one. It is open source so maybe you can add one..